# Why is my Sin() based oscillation resetting my object's position?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, positioning

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

// Makes objects float up & down while gently spinning.
public class Floater : MonoBehaviour {
// User Inputs
public float degreesPerSecond = 15.0f;
public float amplitude = 0.5f;
public float frequency = 1f;
public Transform target;
public float rotateSpeed=2f;
// Position Storage Variables
Vector3 posOffset = new Vector3 ();
Vector3 tempPos = new Vector3 ();

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    // Store the starting position & rotation of the object
    posOffset = transform.position;
}
 
// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    // Spin object around Y-Axis
    transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0f, Time.deltaTime * degreesPerSecond, 0f), Space.World);

    // Float up/down with a Sin()
    tempPos = posOffset;
    tempPos.y += Mathf.Sin (Time.fixedTime * Mathf.PI * frequency) * amplitude;

    transform.position = tempPos;

    //rotate around object
    transform.RotateAround(target.position, Vector3.up, rotateSpeed* Time.deltaTime);
  }
}
```

The object is only floating but it doesn't rotate around the other object, even if I remove all the part that makes it float (there is a comment there). It does rotate around the object but how can I make both of them happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're never updating `posOffset` so you're continually resetting the transform's position.  You only need to store the original `y` position. `x` and `z` are handled by `RotateAround` and `y` is the only variable that's being managed based on its original value.

```
private float startY;

private void Start() {
    startY = transform.position.y;
}

private void Update() {
    // Spin object around Y-Axis
    transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0f, Time.deltaTime * degreesPerSecond, 0f), Space.World);

    // rotate around object
    transform.RotateAround(target.position, Vector3.up, rotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

    // Float up/down with a Sin()
    var yOffset = Mathf.Sin (Time.fixedTime * Mathf.PI * frequency) * amplitude;

    transform.position = new Vector3(
        transform.position.x,
        startY + yOffset,
        transform.position.z);
}
```